# Perl - Mechanize? - How to get all links in a page up to a specific "delimiter" text

Tags: perl, mechanize

These are the modules I have installed.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use XML::Simple;
use LWP::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use Web::Scraper;
#use HTML::Grabber;
```

I am trying to get all links that end in '`.com`' up to an html tag: '`<div class="nogo_class">Proceed No More</div>`' creating an array from the results.

I have looked at various examples I found here and in documentation but, nothing that does this.
Nothing I can wrap my noob mind around anyhow.

So, using the modules I have installed, how can I get all links that end in '`.com`' up to that stopping point: '`<div class="nogo_class">Proceed No More</div>`' into an array?

So, later down I can get the links out with a loop or whatever.
eg `$somearray[$counter];`

I am really inexperienced and hope I asked the question properly. Verbose explanations in any examples will help me learn this.

Thanks for you help.

P.S. the 'nogo_class' is used multiple times in the page but, the 'Proceed No More' text only appears once in the page. ALSO, I am running Perl v5.8.8 and Grabber needs v5.10.0 minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple) to parse the document. Stop parsing `a` tags when you find the text "Proceed No More" in a `div.nogo`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use URI;

my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(handle => \*DATA);

my @interesting_links;

while (my $tag = $p->get_tag(qw'a div')) {
    if ($tag->is_start_tag('div')) {
        my $class = $tag->get_attr('class');
        if (defined($class) and $class eq 'nogo_class') {
            my $text = $p->get_text('/div');
            last if defined($text) and $text eq 'Proceed No More';
        }
    }
    elsif ($tag->is_start_tag('a')) {
        my $href = $tag->get_attr('href');
        next unless defined $href;
        my $uri = URI->new($href);
        my $host = $uri->host;
        next unless $host =~ /[.]com\z/;
        push @interesting_links, $href;
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @interesting_links;

__DATA__
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="http://example.com/link1">Link 1</a>, <a
href="http://example.org/link2">Link 2</a> and <a
href="http://example.com/link3">Link 3</a></p>

<div class="nogo_class">Keep going man!</div>

<p><a href="http://example.com/link4">Link 4</a>, <a
href="http://example.org/link5">Link 5</a> and <a
href="http://example.net/link6">Link
6</a></p>

<div class="nogo_class">Keep going man!</div>

<div class="nogo_class">Proceed No More</div>

<p><a href="#">Link 7</a>, <a href="#">Link 8</a> and <a href="#">Link
9</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great use of this module. This example doesn't include the code to fetch the page in question and it gets the text contents of the A tag and not the href but the OP wasn't clear on what part they're having trouble with nor exactly they want from the links.

Comment: Thank you. But, how do I get the page into this routine? I am trying to get each url 'http://variouslinks.com' before the "delimiter" into the array. I would use mechanize?

Comment: I am trying with: [code]my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(url => 'http://www.aurl.com');[/code] based on your input. I will let you know.

Comment: Well, this works for getting page up to "delimiter" just does not cover my question. This also gets links that end in all other extensions like .org. Need to get Just .com. I need to get the links that end in .com atw to the delimiter putting the links (http://links.com) into an array.

Comment: @Jim_Bo Added the functionality to extract only the links pointing to `.com` domains. I would, however, like to remind you that SO is not a *"do everything for me"* service.

Comment: I am still trying. I have not given up trying to figure this out. This is far from everything @Sinan, just a learning curve. I may be old but, not hapless. ;-/ I do appreciate you pointing the way.